# how to insert html into a text in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, addition, jspdf

I am making a pdf with jsPDF and I want to add a string that works as html.

this is the string:

```
text=`<p>Hello my name is <b>JOSUE</b></p>`
```

this is my code:

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
const doc = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'p',
          unit: 'mm',
          format: 'a4'
        });

doc...

doc.html(text, {
          callback: function (doc) {
            
          },
          x:10,
          y:10
        });

doc...


doc.save()
```

but it does not add the string in pdf, how do I solve it?

Note. I do not want to add the document.body instead of the text, since I have more functions for my pdf